# Kubernetes: Getting name resolution error

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am deploying php and redis to a local minikube cluster but getting below error related to name resolution.

```sh
Warning: Redis::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /app/redis.php on line 4

Warning: Redis::connect(): connect() failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /app/redis.php on line 4

Fatal error: Uncaught RedisException: Redis server went away in /app/redis.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /app/redis.php(5): Redis->ping() #1 {main} thrown in /app/redis.php on line 5
```

I am using below configurations files:

apache-php.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webserver
  labels:
    app: apache
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-apache
        image: webdevops/php-apache
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-code
          mountPath: /app
      volumes:
        - name: app-code
          hostPath:
            path: /minikubeMnt/src
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
  labels:
    app: apache
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: apache
```

redis.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:5.0.4
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
             - containerPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
```

And I am using the below PHP code to access Redis, I have mounted below code into the apache-php deployment.

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect("redis-service", 6379);
echo "Server is running: ".$redis->ping();
```

Cluster dashboard view for the services is given below:

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Thanks in advance.

When I run env command getting below values related to redis and when I use the IP:10.104.115.148 to access redis then it is working fine.

````
REDIS_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.104.115.148:6379
REDIS_SERVICE_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.104.115.148:6379
REDIS_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=6379
REDIS_SERVICE_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.104.115.148
REDIS_SERVICE_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp```
````

Comment: please make sure redis server is running before your webserver. I see webserver deployment is old than redis

Comment: Seems like you are starting your app before redis and it's not finding redis initially

Comment: when i ssh into both pods then both are working. when i ssh into php pod and run "php redis.php" then also getting the name resolution error. i am sure it is some issue that the k8 is not exposing the service by name. Even getting same error after deploying the above configs to digitalocean cluster.

Comment: i am not using redis in some entrypoint or startup script. redis is on and then i call the php file using http request. getting same error when i run the file using cli php.

Comment: if you replace server name with IP, is  it work?

Comment: when i run env command getting below values related to redis and when I use the IP:10.104.115.148 to access redis then it is working fine:

REDIS_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.104.115.148:6379
REDIS_SERVICE_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.104.115.148:6379
REDIS_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=6379
REDIS_SERVICE_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.104.115.148
REDIS_SERVICE_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp

Answer (score 1):

Consider using K8S `liveliness` and `readiness` probes here, to automatically recover from errors. You can find more related information [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-setting-up-health-checks-with-readiness-and-liveness-probes).

And you can use an `initContainer` that check for availability of redis-server using bash `while` loop with `break` and then let php-apache to start. For more information, check **Scenario 2** in [here](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-patterns-the-init-container-pattern).

---

#### Redis Service as Cluster IP

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
spec:
  type: clusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
```

Comment: anmol sharma added few comments above ^^. that may clarify the problem.

Comment: @Saifullahkhan 
=> Redis is usually used as backend service, no need to expose it as NodePort, use clusterIP instead, refer the section in answer above.

=> If setting redis host to `redis-service` is not working try using full dns name like `redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local`

=> Also check if dns service in miniKube is working fine using command `kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system`. For more details on details in debugging DNS checkout this - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/